# Access section key value from another section in config.ini

Tags: python, config, ini

I have a config.ini file

```
[env]
name = local

[dir]
proj_home = /apps/${env:name}/project
```

Python code:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
projHome = config.get('dir', 'proj_home')
```

But projHome value is coming '/apps/${env:name}/project', it should be '/apps/local/project'

Am I doing something wrong in syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `${section:option}` syntax is only available when you're using [extended interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values):

```
>>> cf = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
>>> cf.add_section('env')
>>> cf.set('env', 'name', 'local')
>>> cf.add_section('dir')
>>> cf.set('dir', 'proj_home', '/apps/${env:name}/project')
>>> cf.get('dir', 'proj_home')
'/apps/local/project'
```